# print values of an array of arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am filling an array with a for and this sent him to a role, she will receive and use the foreach I assign the values ​​of the array to my variables and print , however, only the values ​​of the first array and the other shows are ignored.

this code filling an array

```
$return_arr = array();

for ($i=0;$i<$cont-1;$i++)
{
    /* the mysql code for insert multiple data*/


    //The array
    $row_array[$i]['idTicket'] = $idTicket;
    $row_array[$i]['porcionSubtotal'] = $porcionSubtotal[$i];
    $row_array[$i]['cajero'] = $cajero;
    $row_array[$i]['porcionCant'] = $porcionCant[$i];
    $row_array[$i]['tipoPago'] = $tipoPago;
    $row_array[$i]['marca'] = $marca;
    $row_array[$i]['descuento'] = $descuento;
    $row_array[$i]['nombreProducto'] = $nombreProducto;
}

array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
crearTicketVenta($return_arr, $total);
```

my pdf function is

```
function crearTicketVenta($return_arr, $totalVenta){
$total = $totalVenta;
foreach($return_arr as $index => $value){

        $nombre = $value[$index]['nombreProducto'] .'<br>';
        $cantidad = $value[$index]['porcionCant'] .'<br>';
        $importe = $value[$index]['porcionSubtotal'] .'<br>';
        $subtotal = $value[$index]['porcionSubtotal'] .'<br>';
        $idTicket = $value[$index]['idTicket'];
        $cajero = $value[$index]['cajero'];
        $porcionSubtotal = $value[$index]['porcionSubtotal'];
        //unset($return_arr[$index + 1]);
    }
}
```

and the var_dump array is

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(8) { ["idTicket"]=> int(160) ["porcionSubtotal"]=> string(2) "21" ["cajero"]=> string(9) "undefined" ["porcionCant"]=> string(1) "1" ["tipoPago"]=> string(9) "undefined" ["marca"]=> string(5) "ADATA" ["descuento"]=> string(1) "%" ["nombreProducto"]=> string(7) "Carrito" } [1]=> array(8) { ["idTicket"]=> int(160) ["porcionSubtotal"]=> string(3) "135" ["cajero"]=> string(9) "undefined" ["porcionCant"]=> string(1) "1" ["tipoPago"]=> string(9) "undefined" ["marca"]=> string(12) "LIDeditorial" ["descuento"]=> string(1) "%" ["nombreProducto"]=> string(30) "Las cuatro Vidas de Steve Jobs" } } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem, thank you for your answers.

this is a part of my code, this part generates an array.

```
for ($i=0;$i<$cont-1;$i++){
    //the mysql query
    //the array
    $row_array[$i]['idTicket'] = $idTicket;
    $row_array[$i]['porcionSubtotal'] = $porcionSubtotal[$i];
    $row_array[$i]['cajero'] = $cajero;
    $row_array[$i]['porcionCant'] = $porcionCant[$i];
    $row_array[$i]['tipoPago'] = $tipoPago;
    $row_array[$i]['marca'] = $marca;
    $row_array[$i]['descuento'] = $descuento;
    $row_array[$i]['nombreProducto'] = $nombreProducto;
}
    //push the array
    array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
    //send array and value
    crearTicketVenta($return_arr, $total);
```

This is my complete code, this code generates a PDF Voucher.

```
    <?php
function crearTicketVenta($return_arr, $totalVenta){
    // Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
    require_once('includes/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

//Define format date
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$hoy = getdate();
$fechaActual= $hoy['mday'].'-'.$hoy['mon'].'-'.$hoy['year'];
$horaActual= $hoy['hours'].':'.$hoy['minutes'];

//Define variables
$total = $totalVenta;
$nombre = '';
$cantidad = '';
$importe = '';
$subtotal = '';
$idTicket = '';
$cajero = '';
$porcionSubtotal = '';

//The array
foreach($return_arr as $index => $value){   
    if(is_array($value)) {
       foreach ($value as $key => $values) {
            $nombre .= $values['nombreProducto'] .'<br>';
            $cantidad .= $values['porcionCant'] .'<br>';
            $importe .= $values['porcionSubtotal'] .'<br>';
            $subtotal .= $values['porcionSubtotal'] .'<br>';
            $idTicket = $values['idTicket'];//Don't repeat
            $cajero = $values['cajero'];//Don't repeat
            $porcionSubtotal .= $values['porcionSubtotal'];
        }
    }       
}

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Manfred');
$pdf->SetTitle('Comprobante de compra');
$pdf->SetSubject('Comprobante de compra');

// remove default header/footer
//$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, "SOLARA", "No. de Ticket: ".$idTicket."\nLe atendio: ".$cajero);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('times', 'B', 16);
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, 'Comprobante de compra', 0, 'C', 0, 1, '', '', true, 0);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

//Define table
$tbl = <<<EOD
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" >
<thead>
<tr>
<td width="20%"; align="center">Cantidad </td>
<td width="40%"; align="center">Producto</td>
<td width="20%"; align="center">Importe</td>
<td width="20%"; align="center">Subtotal</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%"; align="center">$cantidad<br></td>
        <td width="40%"; align="center">$nombre<br></td>
        <td width="20%"; align="center">$importe<br></td>
        <td width="20%"; align="center">$subtotal<br></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td width="20%"; align="center">Total<br>
        $total
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<center><p  align="center">Fecha y hora de compra:</p></center>
<center><p  align="center">$fechaActual a las $horaActual</p></center>
    <center><p  align="center">Gracias por su preferencia</p></center>
EOD;

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('Ticket No - '.$idTicket.'.pdf', 'D');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look to your data:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(8) { ["idTicket"]=> int(160)    ["porcionSubtotal"]=> string(2) "21" ["cajero"]=> string(9) "undefined" ["porcionCant"]=> string(1) "1" ["tipoPago"]=> string(9) "undefined" ["marca"]=> string(5) "ADATA" ["descuento"]=> string(1) "%" ["nombreProducto"]=> string(7) "Carrito" } [1]=> array(8) { ["idTicket"]=> int(160) ["porcionSubtotal"]=> string(3) "135" ["cajero"]=> string(9) "undefined" ["porcionCant"]=> string(1) "1" ["tipoPago"]=> string(9) "undefined" ["marca"]=> string(12) "LIDeditorial" ["descuento"]=> string(1) "%" ["nombreProducto"]=> string(30) "Las cuatro Vidas de Steve Jobs" } } }
```

`array(1)`

And when displaying the data, you're doing so

```
foreach($return_arr as $index => $value) {

    $nombre = $value[$index]['nombreProducto'] .'<br>';
    $cantidad = $value[$index]['porcionCant'] .'<br>';
    $importe = $value[$index]['porcionSubtotal'] .'<br>';
    $subtotal = $value[$index]['porcionSubtotal'] .'<br>';
    $idTicket = $value[$index]['idTicket'];
    $cajero = $value[$index]['cajero'];
    $porcionSubtotal = $value[$index]['porcionSubtotal'];
    //unset($return_arr[$index + 1]);
}
```

`$return_arr` has only one value, that's why foreach on display one entry.

Use as : `foreach($return_arr[0] as $index => $value) {`

Or change

`array_push($return_arr, $row_array);` to `$return_arr = $row_array;`